# Matlab dimension mismatch when saving a figure with heatmap and legend?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

**Edit: As of R2020b (maybe earlier) this issue is fixed.**

I want a figure that has a heatmap on one side, and some bar plots on the other side. As you an see I am using `uipanel`s to hold the heatmap and the barplots. The following example *shows* the correct figure, but I cannot *save* it.

The issue has something to do with the legend in the bar plot, but the issue goes away when we don't plot the heatmap.

When I save the figure, I get the following error:

```
Error using alternatePrintPath
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.
Error in alternatePrintPath
Error in print (line 83)
pj = alternatePrintPath(pj);
Error in saveas (line 181)
        print( h, name, ['-d' dev{i}] )
Error in mre (line 18)
saveas(fig, 'test.png');
```

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
fig = figure;

heatmap_panel = uipanel('Position', [0, 0, .7, 1]);
heatmap_data = magic(10);
my_heatmap = heatmap(heatmap_panel, heatmap_data);

bars_panel = uipanel('Position', [.7, 0, .3, 1]);
subplot(2, 1, 1, 'Parent', bars_panel);
bar_data = [.2, .4, .4; .3, .3, .4]';
my_bar = bar(bar_data);
my_legend = legend({'group1', 'group2'});

saveas(fig, 'test.png');
```

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using? I am using R2018a and a png file was saved with no error on your example.

Comment: I'm using R2019b

Comment: Can confirm this problem is reproducible. It's going to be hard to solve given alternatePrintPath is a private function. You should definitely submit a ticket to MathWorks if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks I've just submitted a ticket. If they answer my question I'll post it here